# Need help understanding the similarities and differences between various products.

Tags: tensor-products, products, cross-product, outer-product

What is the similarities and difference between the tensor product, outer product, exterior product, inner product, dot product, cross product? Trying to get into understanding all of them.

Any material explaining them would be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: The dot product is a specific example of an inner product.  The outer product is a specific example of tensor product.  The cross product you are thinking of as a binary operation is closely related to the exterior product, but the results are in different spaces.  There is also a generalization of cross products to higher dimensions but requires more inputs the more dimensions you have.  Most of these will be bilinear maps.  Each type of product has its own wikipedia page, for example [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) where you can learn more about them.

Comment: Have you tried reading about it anywhere? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Ya tried to read about them..but its really a huge topic.I was having trouble with the abstract notion of it all I guess.Understanding how something is a generalization of something else like how the tensor product is actually avery abstract ideaand is a generalization of the outerproduct of vectors or Kronecker product of matrices has helped.But after getting thebasic understaing of it all reading theexplanation on the various topichas become a little bit easier.Mathematicians have made a lot ofwords as an abstraction to the idea andnot easy for engineers.Thank you JMoravitz and mathreadler